# Secondary layout rotation problem

Tags: xamarin.ios, rotation

I have an app with a Main view and two secondary views. They are all designed in IB as Landscape layouts. I have a MainViewController class which basically returns true. All the views are designed (I think) to rotate and resize.

If the app starts in Landscape orientation, the secondary views show correctly even if rotated to Portrait. But, if the app starts in Portrait, the secondary layouts never rotate properly, they get cut off on the bottom and run off to the right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced something similar. I am not using interface builder at all in my app and I do all the rotation and resizing logic manually. I have noticed that sometimes during app start the viewControllers InterfaceOrientation is 'Unknown'. This caused me the same behavior. I solved it bu switching the orientation recognition from current viewController to the main NavigationBar of the app. Donno why but this control is always correctly set with its orientation.
If you mean by 'secondary layouts' something that is initially hidden than if I am correct they are not rotated automatically because the are hidden. You have to do it manually.